# Integrate a payment processing service with my MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, payment-gateway, payment

I'm developing a (here comes another one) [SaaS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service) and can't seem to decide on my billing strategy. I'm looking for a payment processor service with low fees, I'm NOT a fan of PayPal, any ideas???

I'm also looking for easy integration with MVC 2

I'm also based outside the US.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authorize.net is reasonably priced and has an excellent developer API.  Plus there are a lot of libraries out there that handle the interaction with their API.

I recommend contacting your bank to find out if they can get you setup with an Authorize.net merchant account.  Then they handle setting it up and making sure the money gets put directly in your account.  The bank also handles all the authorize.net fees so you don't have to deal with authorize.net directly.

I know Wells Fargo and Chase both use Authorize.net from personal experience, you'll need to contact your bank though to find out more.

Answer (score 1):

1) use ssl.

2) get the user to input cc details into a form and post to a controller

3) get the controller to call a webservice with a provider like eway or (yuck) netregistry

4) ?

5) profit.

Answer (score 0):

Since payment processing can be argued as a business logic, I would recommend that calling the payment processing web service (or Http post for that matter) inside of the model by having a submit method implemented in the model. Once you post to the controller, you will receive the model which you can simply call SubmitPayment on it before you return (or redirect to the payment success or payment failure actions)

Answer (score 0):

First decide with fits you best, you can use [this comparison chart](https://www.formstack.com/payment-gateway-comparison), many free and good options

1. based on country
2. currency
3. cards accepted
4. cost (for many you don't
   have to pay any upfront monthly fees)

each have their own dev samples for integration.